# Android transferring data between a wifi direct and non-wifi direct device

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

The Wiki specification of WiFi direct,claims that "Only one of the Wi-Fi devices needs to be compliant with Wi-Fi Direct to establish a peer-to-peer connection that transfers data directly between each other with greatly reduced setup". But from android API it seems to me that both the devices need to be WiFi-Direct enabled or else one will not be able to find the other.

Is this true or is there a way to have p2p sharing between a WiFi direct and a non-WiFi direct enabled devices?

Thanks

Comment: Your questions is solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796765/connect-to-android-devices-using-wifi-direct-without-prompt/29806709#29806709) just like Sato describes it.

Answer (score 1):

following pattern can connect via wifi.

wifi direct device(P2P AP) <-> non-wifi direct device, has wifi(W)

1. P2P AP: do wifi direct api "createGroup()", this api create wifi accesspoint
2. P2P AP: do wifi direct api "requestGroupInfo()", this api returns WifiP2pGroup, that contains wifi accesspoint informations, such as ap name, password and other.
3. (P2P AP to W: tell ap name and password to W device owner)
4. W:  setting app -> wireless -> search and connect wifi accesspoint created by P2P AP device.

if you need auto connect to wifi accesspoint, P2P AP app should have a broadcast accesspoint name and password...

Answer (score 0):

Spec says that non p2p devices can also connect to a p2p GO, provided non p2p client doesn't  support only 11b rates.