# connect to android devices using wifi direct without prompt

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

i am trying to connect two android devices using WIFI direct and i was successful. But the problem is the second device has to accept the a connection prompt after the other device initiates the connection. It is undesirable for what i am trying to achieve. I saw a few post here in stack overflow itself saying that currently its not possible. But came across an app called SUPERBEAM which user WIFI direct but without the prompt. A search in google gave me the following link from xda forum which says

```
SuperBeam creates an access point using Android's WiFi direct API's.     
This essentially works like hotspot mode in old devices, but it is 
guaranteed to work on newer devices like Nexus 7. Moreover, this mode 
allows older devices to connect and receive files without having to 
support WiFi direct's peer-to-peer connections and, more importantly, it 
gets rid of the annoying "accept connection" prompt.
```

But no where i found information on how to implement this. Can anybody help me. Here is the link 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2177133

Comment: Quote: `Ideas, problems & questions: http://support.superbe.am`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could indeed simply use the createGroup function from the API to create a group, which also makes the access point. The first problem here is that the access point name & password are set automatically, and you can not change them.

So, you do need to pass the info to the connecting party, and for this, I would suggest using the local service advertising, and using the instance name there.

Did make simple test app for this and you can find it from [Github under DrJukka/MyWifiMesh](https://github.com/DrJukka/MyWifiMesh), also some discussions on the topic can be found from [my blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=39)

Comment: Can this method be used with PCs? Using createGroup() would allow a laptop see the connection. But will a laptop be able to receive the service broadcast as well? Trying to find a way to edit the WIFI SSID (WIFI Manager might help with this) and remove the password requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve using Xposed framework. You need add the code and install the App. The phone needs to be rooted in order for it to work. I have tested it on multiple Samsung phones and it works.
Check this answer for details: [How to auto-accept Wi-Fi Direct connection requests in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544906/how-to-auto-accept-wifi-direct-connection-request-in-android)

Comment: as already mentioned in the question i have gone through this post. I know it can be done after rooting the device. But superbeam achieves it without that. Wanted to get more info how to do it.